# How do I test that command sends subprocess output to stderr?

Tags: subprocess, python-click

I implemented a Click CLI that will run `subprocess` processes, but send their `stdout` to `stderr`, so that `stdout` only contains the command's specific output, e.g.

```
@click.command()
def cli():
  subprocess.run(["echo", "hello world"], stdout=sys.stderr)
  click.echo("result")
```

And I want to test that `"hello world"` goes to `stderr` and `"result"` goes to `stdout`. Specifically, if I removed the `stdout=sys.stderr` parameter, I want my test to fail.

```
def test_foo():
    runner = CliRunner(mix_stderr=False)
    result = runner.invoke(cli, catch_exceptions=False)
    assert result.stdout == "result"
    assert result.stderr == "hello world"
```

This doesn't work though, because it sets `sys.stderr` to a handle without a file descriptor, which causes `subprocess` to fail:

```
            # Assuming file-like object
>           c2pwrite = stdout.fileno()
E           io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

Is this a Click bug, or is there a workaround, or is this just not supported? I would like to avoid writing a full integration test that calls my CLI via `subprocess` instead of `CliRunner`.

Answer (score -1):

You can patch `subprocess.run` and mock the stdout option so that it responds to the `fileno` method.

In the POSIX standard, standard error stream file descriptor number is `2`. You can have your function return that.

You must then use the `capfd` fixture to capture the standard error stream and perform your assertion.

```py
import io
import subprocess
from unittest.mock import patch

from click.testing import CliRunner

from .. import main


def test_foo(capfd):
    orig_run = subprocess.run
    def patch_run(args, stdout=None):
        assert stdout, 'You must configure stdout option'
        assert isinstance(stdout, io.IOBase), 'stdout option must implemement stream interface'
        assert stdout.name == '<stderr>', 'Set stdout option to stderr'
        stdout.fileno = lambda: 2 # write to standard err fd
        rv = orig_run(args, stdout=stdout)
        return rv

    with patch.object(subprocess, 'run', patch_run):
        runner = CliRunner(mix_stderr=False)
        result = runner.invoke(main.cli, catch_exceptions=False)
        assert result.stdout == "result\n"

    captured = capfd.readouterr()
    assert captured.err == "hello world\n"
```

Comment: No, that doesnt test what I want it to test. I want to test that the function sends it to stderr on normal operation. If someone erroneously changes the source to `stdout=sys.stdout`, your test would not detect that